# how resolve this difference equation used Laplace transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Solve the equation or system of equations using the Laplace transform.

I need a solution to this task. Anyone could do this for me?

\begin{cases}  x' +y' -x = 1 \\ x' + 2y' = 0 \end{cases}

$$x(0) = 0$$

$$ y(0) = 1$$

Comment: Write the system as $Au'=f$ and use the usual methods.

Comment: I can't solve the Laplace equations in general, I don't know how started. I need resolved this example because on my University on labs make simple, but on test we have this type example. But Laplace method is difficult for me.

Comment: Okay. You should maybe try solving equations with one dependent variable and extend it to several variables.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ X(s)=L\{x(t)\}, Y(s)=L\{y(t)\} $$
and then
$$ L\{x'(t)\}=sX(s)-x(0)=sX(s), L\{y'(t)\}=sY(s)-y(0)=sY(s)-1. $$
Taking Laplace transform for these two equations gives
$$ sX(s)+sY(s)-1-X(s)=\frac1s, sX(s)+2sY(s)-2=0$$
or
$$ (s-1)X(s)+sY(s)=1+\frac1s, sX(s)+2sY(s)=-2.$$
Solving $X(s)$ and $Y(s)$ and taking inverse Laplace transform, you will get the answer. I omit the detail.

Comment: So, from $$ sX(s)+2sY(s)=-2$$ i calculate sY(s) so:  $$sY(s)=-1-\frac{sX(s)}{2}$$. and insert to $$(s-1)X(s)+sY(s)=1+\frac1s$$ so: $$(s-1)X(s) -1-\frac{sX(s)}{2} = 1 + \frac1s$$

Comment: Okey, i resovled this problems. Thanks for your tips!